# Generate Random String and Writing to File

Tags: java, performance, random, file, io

my task is to generate random strings and store in a file till the size of file is less than **10MB**. My approach towards this problem is as follows.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File file = new File("Hello.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        while (file.length() <= 1e+7) {
            writer.write(Generator.generateRandomString(12, Generator.Mode.ALPHANUMERIC));
            writer.write("\n");
            writer.write(Generator.generateRandomString(12, Generator.Mode.NUMERIC));
            writer.write("\n");
            writer.write(Generator.generateRandomString(12, Generator.Mode.ALPHA));
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000f + " seconds");
    }
}
```

It takes about **100.495 seconds** to complete on my **i3 processor with 4GB of RAM**. So my question is, how to improve this performance? Why is the performance so poor? Is there any another workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the repeated calls to `file.length()` that is slowing you down.

Let's try this

```
while (file.length() <= 1e+7) {
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
}
```

On my machine that took ~51s.

Now let's try this:

```
for (int length = 0; length <= 1e+7; length += 39) {
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
}
```

Approximately 0.3s. And a quick sanity check:

> ```
> $ du -h Hello.txt
> 9.6M    Hello.txt
> ```

---

There's a problem with the original method, which is the interaction of `file.length()` and using a buffered writer. Let's try to write up to 400 bytes:

```
while (file.length() <= 400) {
  writer.write("abcdefghijkl");
  writer.write("\n");
}
```

We actually end up with a lot more because of the buffered writer:

> ```
> $ du -b Hello.txt
> 8203    Hello.txt
> ```

A similar problem is also present in the method presented here: we end up writing 403 bytes, not because of buffering but because of how we're counting. If you want to be precise about the total file size, you will need to modify it.

Comment: Can you provide some insight on why length+=39. Btw your code works blazingly fast.

Comment: Nice catch. I never realized exactly how slow `Files.length()` is. I was in the process of working things up 'my own way' using a DataOutputStream which has a `size()` method, but your 'track' got the right answer first.

Comment: @ajkumar25 sorry, wrote it in a hurry. Three strings of twelve characters + 3 new line characters = 39 characters = 39 bytes (assuming one byte per character -- which is not *necessarily* true, just assuming UTF-8 encoding and all chars printed are single-byte; you should specify the encoding). Note this isn't an example of good code, I just wanted to demonstrate the speed difference. Also there may be a difference in the output of the two methods due to buffering.